# SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 1 , happen when i try to post this type of array json data to the mongodb , how to fix this?

Tags: json, next.js13

the error is as follows
[image]

this is content inside the members

```
 {
    "name": "STRING1",
    "japaneseName": "",
    "birthday": "",
    "band": "",
    "cv": "",
    "instrument": "",
    "instrumentImage": "",
    "description": "String",
    "introductionMovie": ""
  }
```

and it should have the images with type of array also, I also try to put the images like this bandMembers[0]images[0] and bandMembers[]images[] and it also didn't work.

[image]
this is the mongodb model that I'm using

[image]

and also this what the code to save the model in Nextjs 13

Comment: You are sending form data, not JSON, but you are parsing it as JSON... that can't be right. (Also, `(await result)` should be simply `result` because the value was already awaited in the previous line, but that's not the issue.)

Comment: so , how I can send the image file in the body section because I can successfully send the Json data is in the body -> raw -> Json , but in the raw section cannot send with type of file